# Set Default Checked Items in a CheckedLIstBox VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have a code that retrieve the data from SQL Server to a CheckedListBox

```
    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT Facility FROM Database.dbo.Facility"
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
    connection.Open()
    Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    Dim var As New DataTable
    Dim source As New BindingSource
    source.DataSource = dataReader
    CheckList_Facility.DataSource = source
    CheckList_Facility.ValueMember = "Facility"
    connection.Close()
```

The result works well, assume I have the result:

```
[ ]AA
[ ]BB
[ ]CC
```

I would like to check IF there is "BB" then it automatically checked "BB" so that

```
[ ]AA
[X]BB
[ ]CC
```

I tried but failed. Something likes

```
     For Each item In CheckedList_Facility.Items
        If (item("Facility").ToString() = "BBB") Then
            CheckedList_Region.SelectedValue = True
    Next
```

To try if it does actually return the string, I tested the code

```
For Each item In CheckedList_Facility.Items
    MsgBox(item("Facility").ToString())
Next
```

**It does return "AA", "BB" , "CC"**

Comment: When you debug through it, does it notice that `item("Facility").ToString` is "BBB"? Does it just not check the checkbox?

Comment: If there is a BB where? As far as I can see you're only retrieving one field from the database, and that's the label for the checkbox.

Comment: @Adruan Wragg, it is not a label but a collection of items.  The retrieving code works - it does returns a list of facilities as I stated

Comment: @Alex, if I use the code 
            MsgBox(item("Region").ToString()) only, it does show the facility

Comment: @user2103670 So what is the problem exactly? It doesn't check the checkbox? The `item("ITEM")` is not returning the right info? I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: item("Facility").ToString() returns the right information. However, even there is "BB" in the CheckedListBox. If it run the code, it returns this error: `"List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change.`"

Comment: Basically, I have the retrieving code runs at run time so I have a CheckedListBox of All facility, and have a button "bt_default" to set some default facility in the CheckedListBox. In this case, it is "BB"

Comment: In your examples, I think you are confusing the "Region" with the "Facility".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code

```
Dim queryString As String = "SELECT Facility FROM Database.dbo.Facility"
Dim checkedValue As String = "BB"
Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)

connection.Open()

Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

If dataReader.HasRows Then
    Do While dataReader.Read
        Dim facility As String = dataReader.Item("Facility").ToString()
        Dim checkedState As Boolean = facility = checkedValue

        CheckList_Facility.Items.Add(facility, checkedState)
    Loop
End If

connection.Close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just tested your code and it does..WORK :) thank again